# How can I run a sql query after clicking a button in Odoo?

Tags: postgresql, button, odoo, odoo-8

I use Odoo8 and I'm trying to create a custom module to generate a report after adding a date to the datefield.

So my question is: How can I run a SQL query in python class after cliking a button in form view?

Answer (score 7):

XML view:

```
<button name="open_something" string="Name of button" type="object" />
```

Python code:

```
@api.multi
def open_something(self):
    self.ensure_one()

    self.env.cr.execute("SQL query")
    result = cr.fetchall()

    ...
```

Keep in mind that you should use ORM methods because some constraints are not in the database

Comment: Hi ChesuCR; Thank you for the answer. I will try it now.

Comment: Could you mark the question as correct question if it helped you? Thanks